# libGDX Causing Multitouch Problems

Tags: java, android, input, multi-touch, libgdx

I am working on a game with a virtual joystick in the bottom right corner of the screen and a "move" button in the bottom left. So you use the joystick to point the character in the right direction and press the "move" button to go forward in that direction. This was all working great until today and now when I press on the screen to go forward my joystick is being affected. I know it is not a coding problem because I haven't opened the file that handles touches for 8 days and it has been working fine. Also after I close my app and then use another app that is completely separate from libGDX the multitouch is having the same issue. So do you guys think this is a problem with libGDX, my device, or am I just not coding the multitouch correctly for libGDX? I am using a `Stage` and the controls are `Actor`s on the `Stage` I should note that after I restart my phone, the other app that is not using libGDX works correctly. It is only after I open my libGDX based game. So frustrated with this that I am about to give up on libGDX. I am happy to post any code that is requested.

EDIT: Please see comments below. This seems to be a specific issue with the Galaxy Nexus and probably some other Samsung devices as well. This libGDX based app has had no issues on other devices such as original droid, and ASUS Transformer tablet.

Comment: So your saying that the multi-touch problem occurs on a none-libgdx app as well??

Comment: Yes, but only after I open the libgdx based app. If I restart my device and open the non-libgdx based app everything works fine until I open the libgdx based app. It's very weird. I've tested this on a Galaxy Nexus as well as an original droid. Same results. Aside from that I am hoping to just see what other people are doing for their multitouch on a stage with multiple actors being touched. To compare to what I have done. I'm very far into developing my game and have had no problems until now.

Comment: From your description, this sounds more like a framework issue, you might want to raise an issue on the [libgdx google code page](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/list).

Comment: Thanks, I will probably try that if I can't get anywhere with it by tomorrow.

Comment: Well looks like this is a device specific problem. I have retested on both my original droid and Galaxy Nexus and it seems to be just the nexus with the problem. My above test on the original droid must have included some buggy code as I have been changing it like crazy trying to figure things out. Here is the link to the issue http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=23044

Comment: It's not a libgdx specific problem, it seems to be  a problem specific to the Galaxy Nexus. Observe all these nice videos. http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=galaxy+nexus+multitouch&oq=galaxy+nexus+mul&aq=0p&aqi=p-p1&aql=&gs_l=youtube-psuggest.3.0.35i39.826l2593l0l3979l16l16l0l0l0l0l170l1460l10j5l15l0.

Comment: Thanks, yea when it first happened I could not figure out what was going on! But glad I found out it was the device problem because I love working with libGDX!

Comment: Please add and accept your own answer so we don't have to read the whole comment thread in the future :)

Comment: @ashes999 Good idea, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is not a libGDX problem at all... Nor was it a problem with any of my code. There seems to be a bug in the way the Galaxy Nexus handles multitouch. You can view the bug report at this [link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=23044). Seems that as of 4.0.4 there still is no fix for this bug. I am still currently running a VZW Galaxy Nexus with 4.0.2, I guess all we can do is wait and put a disclaimer in our games until (if ever) it is fixed.

By locking and unlocking the device, the problem does go away (sometimes), but will quickly come back if I go to my homescreen and re-open the app.